# How do I inspect table variables and temporary tables from within a debugging session in SSMS 2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, debugging, remote-debugging

I'm stepping through a stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio 2008 (SSMS). The code creates some table variables as well as temporary # tables that I would like to inspect as I go along. Now the other local variables I can see in the "Locals" window and while the table variables are listed there, I can't see their contents. I would also like to inspect the # temp tables but again any select statement that I want to run against them will need to come from the same session as the code that I'm stepping through.

Is this possible in the SSMS 2008 debugger?

Comment: Dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900857/how-to-see-the-values-of-a-table-variable-at-debug-time-in-t-sql

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I built [a procedure](https://github.com/FilipDeVos/sp_select) which will display the content of a temp table from another database connection. (which is not possible with normal queries).
Note that it uses DBCC PAGE & the default trace to access the data so only use it for debugging purposes.

Comment: Excellent procedure - is there a way to do the same thing for table variables e.g.  select * from ATmytable ?

Comment: You can if you find the temp table name. See this answer for more info http://stackoverflow.com/a/8561729/619960

Comment: I've used `select * From tempdb.sys.tables order by modify_date;` to get the latest local table, I've executed `exec dbo.sp_select 'tempdb..#AE512833'` but it returns: `The table [tempdb..#AE512833] does not exist`. Same with when I remove the `tempdb.` part. But I see the table name listed in the first query. Any ideas? :^)

Comment: You have to use the original temp table name, not the virtual name in tempdb. Your #AE512833 was created with a different name. This is the name you need to use.

Answer (score 1):

This is largely the same question as this one: [How to see the values of a table variable at debug time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900857/how-to-see-the-values-of-a-table-variable-at-debug-time-in-t-sql)

It appears that the short answer is: NO! This hasn't been implemented in SSMS 2008.

See this post on Microsoft Connect: [SQL Debugging - All About Tables: Table Variables, #Temp, ##Global Temp, Source (Input) and Output Tables](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/334684/sql-debugging-all-about-tables-table-variables-temp-global-temp-source-input-and-output-tables)

Answer (score 1):

What I do in a complex proc is add an input varaiable with a default value of 0 to the end of whatever variables I have called @test. (by doing it this way, I won't break any exisiting calls to the proc)

Then at each point where I might want to see the values of a table variable or temp table I put an if statement and I might even add a column so I know at what point I am looking at the table:

IF @test = 1
BEGIN
SELECT 'after updating field 3' as TestStep, *  FROM #temp
END

Now they only run if running in test mode and I can see whatever I need to when debugging  a problem two years from now. I also print any dynamic SQl statments I created in the test mode as well.