# Getting columns from temporary @table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table declared in a stored procedure like this:

```
declare @tableName table (ID bigint,
                            Column1 bigint,
                            Column2 datetime,
                            createdBy nvarchar(100),
                            dateAdded nvarchar(12),
                            Type nvarchar(10)
                            )
```

I want to retrieve the column names so I tried using:

```
select c.name 
from sys.objects o
join sys.columns c
on o.object_id = c.object_id
where o.name = object_id('tempdb..#tableName')
and c.name != 'id' 
ORDER BY CASE c.name 
                    when 'type' then 1
                    when 'createdBy' then 2
                    when 'Column2' then 3
                    when 'dateAdded' then 4
                    when 'Column1' then 5
END
```

This returns error

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'ActivitiesResource' to data type int.

I tried removing the order by and part of the where clause incase they was causing an issue, but it still returns an error. I have also tried `where o.name = object_id('tempdb..@tableName')` (with an @) but it throws the same error.

How do I get the column names for this temporary table?

Comment: You can't use system views for variable tables. You will have to switch to a temporal table (with the hashtag `#`) or a physical one if you want to retrieve it's columns from there. You could treat the variable table as XML and employ some black magic to retrieve it's column names tho.

Comment: @EzequielLópez, I think you mean "temporary table", not "temporal table" (although he could get the columns of either from tempdb).

Comment: In the post that Gordon links to in his answer, a commenter wonders how you can not know the columns of a table variable declared *in the same batch*. Even if we're talking codegen, the thing generating the code knows the columns!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
where o.name = object_id('tempdb..#tableName')
```

You are comparing a name to an object id.  I'm not sure what you are really trying to do here, because you have a hard-coded name in the column.  The table name has nothing to do with the temporary table, so this approach will not work.

Because table variables are handled differently from temporary tables, the system tables may not do what you want.  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14369359/get-definitive-names-for-columns-from-table-variable) is an answer on retrieving the names using XML.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, you're always on hand for SQL questions! I was just trying to get a list of the column names to iterate through. I didn't realise that temporary tables and table variables behaved so differently - the XML approach is way too complicated when I can just use a temp table instead.

Answer (score 0):

That is a [table variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/table-transact-sql).  It only lives for the life of procedure.  There is no reason to record the columns in a system table.

`ID bigint` seems off.  Table variables should not have a lot of rows.

You may be looking for a [temporary table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql).  It is denoted by starting with #.

[Comparing Table Variables with Temporary Tables](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Temporary+Tables/66720/)